# Moment.js is improperly converting 12 hour time to military time

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm using moment.js to convert 12hr time to 24hr time and I keep getting unexpected results.

```
moment("01:30 AM", ["hh:mm A"]).format("HH:hh") 
moment("01:00 PM", ["hh:mm A"]).format("HH:hh")
moment("01:02 AM", ["hh:mm A"]).format("HH:hh")
```

all get converted to: `1001`.

Not sure how I can fix this or what exactly I'm doing wrong. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You are using `"HH:hh"` instead of `"HH:mm"` as parameter of `format`, I think that your question could be closed as typo.

Comment: Yes this too is an error, but it isn't suposed to return `1001`, using the sabe codei got `10:01`. Can you show the entire function where you're using this piece of code?

Comment: Think there's even a typo with your result because there's no way it can produce `1001` - more like `01:01`

Comment: Humbled by my stupidity, I thank you for pointing out my mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `format("HH:mm")` instead of `format("HH:hh")`. `hh` stands for 01-12 hour while `mm` stands for 01-59 minute. See [`format`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) docs.

Here a working sample:

```js
console.log( moment("01:30 AM", "hh:mm A").format("HH:mm") );
console.log( moment("01:00 PM", "hh:mm A").format("HH:mm") );
console.log( moment("01:02 AM", "hh:mm A").format("HH:mm") );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
moment("01:15 AM", ["hh:mm A"]).format("HH:mm");
```